# method does not override method from its superclass . Android Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, overriding, onclicklistener

fragment1:

```
public class fragment1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageButton but, but1, but2;
    ImageView view;
    @Override << this one
    public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, null);
        but = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton11);
        but.setOnClickListener(this);
        but1 = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        but1.setOnClickListener(this);
        but2 = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        but2.setOnClickListener(this);
        return myView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        main xxx = (main)getActivity();
        switch (v.getId()) {
       case R.id.imageButton11:
                xxx.str="but1";
                break;
..
            }}
```

main:

```
Fragment frag1 = new fragment1();
    fr1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fTrans.replace(R.id.frameLayout2, frag1);
                    fTrans.addToBackStack(null);
                    fTrans.commit();
                }
            });
```

method does not override method from its superclass in fragment1(first override)
but without "implemets View.OnClickListener" it works

Comment: which method are you talking about ?? onClick ?
can you show us your imports ??

Comment: first one,in fragment1

Comment: can you show your imports ?

Comment: - import android.app.Fragment; import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
   import android.content.res.Resources; import android.graphics.Bitmap;
   import android.graphics.Canvas; import
   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable; import
   android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable; import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.Log; import android.view.LayoutInflater; import
   android.view.View; import android.view.ViewGroup; import
   android.widget.Button; import android.widget.ImageButton; import
   android.widget.ImageView; import android.widget.Toast;

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Spelling mistake. Name the method `onCreateView` instead of `OnCreateView`.

Comment: Thanks for the question and the answer!  I had same mistake over an half hour: OnStart vs. onStart :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the android sdk but I think you need something like this

```
Fragment frag1 = new fragment1(){
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
              fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
              fTrans.replace(R.id.frameLayout2, frag1);
              fTrans.addToBackStack(null);
              fTrans.commit();
         }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

return your inflated view

```
public View onCreateView(.....) {
...
...

return InputFragmentView;
}
```

and change OnCreateView to onCreateView.
you can tap ctrl+o to get it ready ^^

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was not extending it from  Fragment. Make sure you extend your fragment from `Fragment` class.

```
public class fragment1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
   @Override
///   public View onCreateView.......
}
```